# C# - Delay at code start

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

I want to make some delay on my code
I used **Thread.Sleep**
But my programs go to not responding after some Threads
And then goes out of not responding after the program ended its processes
I want to use something better ... Like Thread

```
AddToConsole("text",milliseconds)
```

And the AddToConsole Void :

```
Appendline(text);

Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve but with `Task<T>` you can use Task.Delay() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please post your code. Is there a UI involved? You could create a  Background Worker or Task, and do your sleep in there before processing further.

Comment: Actually i want to create some fake processes , and dont want background worker ,

Comment: I created a code like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to make delay in code with method (void)

**Task.Delay(millisecond).Wait()**

And delayed successfully without ant freezes ...